# Send local personalized notifications without login

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have been trying to find an answer for a while now. I am creating a react native App, and want to send personalized notifications to a user. I only want to ask the user for their name and number, and don't want to make them create an account. Is there a way i can save this info in firestore?

Right now for firestore the only way I see to save user data is to first make them sign in.

```
auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
```

I just want to be able to get a users name and save it in a database, to then be able to send notifications like "Good Job John Doe". My app has no need for an email and password auth.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [anonymous authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth) to create temporary anonymous accounts.  This can be linked to a user if they decide to sign up to your app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use firebase firestore to store user information without using authentication.

Just simply ask the user about their name and number, save it in the firestore. Then using Firebase Cloud Messaging subscribe to a topic which will be unique to the user (name+number or something like that). Then using firebase cloud function or manually you can send notifications to each individual user